# Delete multiple rows based on single blank in any column Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like:

```
|      Datetime     |   Rainfall   |     Flow  |
| ----------------- | ------------ | --------- |
|  3/19/2018 12:05  |       1      |    5.85   |
|  3/19/2018 12:10  |       2      |    4.47   |
|  3/19/2018 12:15  |       0      |  (BLANK)  |        |
|  3/19/2018 12:20  |       0      |    2.62   |
...
|  3/19/2018 13:00  |       1      |    5.85   |
...
```

It is time series data on a 5-minute interval for rainfall and flow and my objective is to convert this to hourly data. The data has blanks either in the flow or rainfall columns and if there is a blank in either of these columns, I want to delete all the rows for that hour of data (I only want to keep data that has a full hours worth of data) .

For example, in the table above I would delete all of the data for 12:00 - 12:55.

So far I have gotten to converting the data to hourly but realized I likely need to delete the hour-blank rows before resampling to 1H:

```
rain_hourly = rain.set_index('Date & Time').resample('1h').sum()
flow_hourly = flow.set_index('Date & Time').resample('1h').mean()
df_hourly = rain_hourly.merge(flow_hourly, how='left', on='Date & Time')
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I've made an answer to your question below, but would also suggest looking into [pd.interpolate()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.interpolate.html#pandas-series-interpolate) Try running `df.interpolate(axis=1)` and inspect the results~ There's even a `time` method that would be worth researching more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like this :

```
import numpy as np 
df_hourly['Flow']=df_hourly['Flow'].replace('', np.nan)
df_hourly=df_hourly.loc[df_hourly['Flow'].notna(),:].copy()
```

Using `replace` should do the work I think , now you just need to pass a list instead of one feature

Comment: I think the problem with doing it with the df_hourly is that when I take the sum or the mean, it no longer is blank for that hour - in the above example my hourly row would have an average flow of (5.85 + 4.47 + 2.62 )/ 3 instead of NaN

Answer (score 1):

To remove the whole hour:

1. Ensure that datetime is the proper format with something like `pd.to_datetime()`. And that NaN values are formatted correctly. `.replace(<whatblanklookslike>, pd.NA)`
2. Make new columns for date and hour:

- `df['hour'] = df['Datetime'].dt.hour`
- `df['date'] = df['Datetime'].dt.date`

3. Group elements by date and hour:

- `grouped = df.groupby(['date', 'hour'])`

4. Filter the groups, we only want groups where all values aren't NaN:

- `df = grouped.filter(lambda x: x.notna().all().all())`

Simplified example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar'],
                    'B' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                    'C' : [2.0, 5., pd.NA, 1., 2., 9.]})
grouped = df.groupby('A')
df = grouped.filter(lambda x: x.notna().all().all())
print(df)
```

Output:

```
     A  B    C
1  bar  2  5.0
3  bar  4  1.0
5  bar  6  9.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I think I managed to get it to work by addressing the blanks and NaNs and then using .resample('1h') with .apply(lambda x: np.sum() and apply(lambda x: np.mean() instead of the .sum() and .mean() I was using as that seemed to not address the NaNs.

Answer (score 1):

Dataframe contains blank:

```
                 Date  Rainfall     Flow
0 2022-04-26 12:00:00         0        0
1 2022-04-26 12:05:00         1  (BLANK)
2 2022-04-26 12:10:00         2        2
3 2022-04-26 12:15:00         3        3
4 2022-04-26 12:20:00         4        4
```

First I created a column that has the hour, and then a temp column that concatenates rainfall and flow columns to check if one of them contains blank (there are many ways to do this). Then I created a function to check for blanks, and then drop all rows that have an hour containing a blank in one of the two columns.

```
from datetime import datetime as dt

df["hour"] = df["Date"].dt.hour
df["day"] = df["Date"].dt.day
df["res"] = df["Rainfall"].astype(str) + df["Flow"].astype(str)


def blank(row):
    if "(BLANK)" in row:
        return "YES"
    else:
        return "NO"

df["blank"] = df["res"].apply(blank)

to_del0 = set()
to_del1 = set()
for i, k in df.iterrows():
    if df.at[i, "blank"] == "YES":
        to_del0.add(df.at[i, "hour"])
        to_del1.add(df.at[i, "day"])

df.drop( df.index[ (df['hour'].isin(to_del0)) & (df["day"].isin(to_del1)) ], inplace=True)
df = df[["Date", "Rainfall", "Flow"]]
df.head()
```

The result:

```
                  Date  Rainfall Flow
12 2022-04-26 13:00:00        12   12
13 2022-04-26 13:05:00        13   13
14 2022-04-26 13:10:00        14   14
15 2022-04-26 13:15:00        15   15
16 2022-04-26 13:20:00        16   16
```

Comment: This will delete data for that hour for ALL DAYS where an hour on ANY day has a "(BLANK)".

Comment: @BeRT2me yes correct, I have edited the answer. I added a day column the same way I did for hour, and add the condition to drop function.